# Compatibility Issue with Flutter Project on Android 12 and Later Versions

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-compatibility

I have a Flutter project and I developed it in Flutter 1.20.0. However, I'm getting a warning in the Google Play Store that the app is incompatible with Android 12 and higher. I have taken several steps to resolve this issue but still no solution. I have taken several steps to resolve this issue but still no solution. Here are the steps I tried:

I updated my flutter version(from 1.20.0 to 3.10.6) and updated the packages in the project.
I published the app on Google Play Store for internal testing but the compatibility issue remains.

I tried different Android API levels, but none of the levels fixed the issue.

- API Level 16+
- API Level 33+

I changed the compileSdkVersion value, but that didn't fix the problem either.

- compileSdkVersion 21
- compileSdkVersion 33
- compileSdkVersion 34

I changed the targetSdkVersion but still the problem persists.

- targetSdkVersion 34

Google Play Screenshots :

[image]

[image][image]

#### Google Policy Alert

[image: From play console]

#### Proof of compatibility

[image]

Comment: you may need to upgrade your packages and your problem may go, some packages my be old so you should consider finding another one

Comment: @AbdallaTawfik Thanks for your comment.  I installed the latest versions of the packages and if there is no new version, I removed that package from my project. none of them worked, still has compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I asked Google support and they told me I could make staged rollouts.

If there was a problem, I would be able to roll back my update.

That's why I released it for 5% of my users.

After going through the approval process, the compatibility issue was resolved.

Then I released it to 100% of my users and then the problem was completely solved.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project go to this file `android > app > src > build.gradle`.

Make sure you keep

`minSdkVersion 21` or set it based on your requirement.

`targetSdkVersion 33` or 34 if you're developing for android 14

`compileSdkVersion 33`

targetSdkVersion  & compileSdkVersion should be same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with the numbers you said but the result did not change, here is the error compatibility issue. Do you have another idea? For example, could it be related to the gradle version?

Comment: that warning you mentioned is about android sdk version only. So you first focusing on that one. After entering the above values did you publish the app again in testing track?

Comment: yes i set targetSdkVersion 33 and set compileSdkVersion 33 then build and i uploaded bundle to google play console and then wait for internal test to be published. then i saw it was published but i couldn't download it because there was a compatibility issue.

Comment: Is that happening on that particular mobile device only?

Comment: Not only my phone has the same problem, but also other real phones.